# Showing Buttons in list view

Tags: android, listview

I want to create android app about an article that contains 30 chapters so i am to make 30 buttons every button will contain different text stories so please tell me how can i show these 30 buttons in list view instead of showing in normal linear layout of vertical orientation please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple tutorial containing listview with Button. On click of button, based on position, you can show content:
[Listview Tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9e8439/create-custom-listener-on-button-in-listitem-listview-in-a/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom listview / recycler view Please take look into [this](http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial).